# “Table of content” nested tree out of flat materialized paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialized-path-pattern

I have this array of paths:

```rb
[
 "Shape Up.Introduction.Growing Pains",
 "Shape Up.Shaping.Principles of Shaping.Wireframes are too concrete",
 "Shape Up.Shaping.Principles of Shaping.Words are too abstract",
 "Shape Up.Introduction.Six-week cycles",
 "Shape Up.Shaping.Steps to shaping"
]
```

Each segment is separated with a `.`.

I need to render a Table of Contents in the view.

What's the simplest way to transform the array into a nested hash? Or perhaps there's a better structure / approach to generate the required html out of this?

**UPD**

```rb
[
 "Shape Up.Introduction.Growing Pains",
 "Shape Up.Shaping.Principles of Shaping.Wireframes are too concrete",
 "Shape Up.Shaping.Principles of Shaping.Words are too abstract",
 "Shape Up.Introduction.Six-week cycles",
 "Shape Up.Shaping.Steps to shaping"
].inject({}) {|h,i|
  t = h; i.split(".").each {|n| t[n] ||= {}; t = t[n]}; h
}
```

Gives a hash tree structure that I need:

```rb
{
    "Shape Up" => {
        "Introduction" => {
              "Growing Pains" => {},
            "Six-week cycles" => {}
        },
             "Shaping" => {
            "Principles of Shaping" => {
                "Wireframes are too concrete" => {},
                     "Words are too abstract" => {}
            },
                 "Steps to shaping" => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of what you've tried

Comment: What do you mean "nested hash"? Can you show what the desired output is? In general, `reduce`, `each_with_object`, `group_by`, or `index_by` are ways to turn an array into a hash

Comment: the code you've created seems perfectly good to me. I doubt it can be simplified further.